# How to test if SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is active

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my use case I have a `scriptMain.bat` calling a `scriptSub.bat`.
In the called `scriptSub.bat` it is required that `DelayedExpansion` is being enabled.

Since I have to share variable settings with `scriptMain.bat` and `scriptSub.bat` (**updated 5-May-2023**: and I don't want to share settings via call parameter references since of the number of settings made by `scriptSub.bat`), the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` command must be performed in `scriptMain.bat` before calling `scriptSub.bat`.

So I would like to check in `scriptSub.bat`, if `DelayedExpansion` is actually ON.

I did implement those scripts like this - and it seems to work, but I would like to know if there is a simpler solution available.

`scriptMain.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM scriptMain.bat for both cases:
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CALL scriptSub.bat
ENDLOCAL

REM Now without ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SETLOCAL
CALL scriptSub.bat
ENDLOCAL
```

`scriptSub.bat` (**Updated 8-May-2023** - simplified according to answer by [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)):

```
REM scriptSub.bat:
IF "!!" == "" (
  ECHO Delayed expansion is ON
)  ELSE (
  ECHO Delayed expansion is OFF
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Output executing `scriptMain.bat`:

```
Delayed expansion is ON
Delayed expansion is OFF
```

Comment: What about something like this: ```If "!!" == "" (Echo Delayed expansion is ON) Else Echo Delayed expansion is OFF```?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_dest=somewhere"&GOTO !_dest!

:!_dest!
ECHO delayedexpansion NOT enabled
GOTO :EOF

:somewhere
ECHO delayedexpansion IS enabled
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you try to solve the wrong problem.
You search for a detection of the delayed expansion mode, but you should solve the problem, that a called batch file can return a value or variable without the need for the caller to prepare something.

The solution could be one of the various techniques of returning a variable out of a `setlocal` scope

### main.bat

```
@echo off
set "var="
call child.bat
echo The content of var:
set var
```

### child.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set temp=!time!

(
  endlocal
  set "var=%temp%"
)
```

Or for more complex content

### child.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "temp=;Docs&"Programs^&"..."

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (""!temp!"") do (
  endlocal
  set "var=%%~a"
)
```